# How can I stream data to a program that expects to read data from a file that is given as a argument?

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection, arguments

I have a huge gzipped file and I want a program (4s-import in this case) to read it. It takes a lot of time to first unzip the file and then call the program with the path to the file as an argument. Would it be possible to do something like:

```
zcat huge.gz | 4s-import <SOME MAGIC>
```

where SOME-MAGIC is like a path to an abstract file that contains stdin?

The much slower and more disk space consuming alternative that I have to do otherwise is:

```
zcat huge.gz > huger
4s-import huger
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use the process substitution operator `<()` of `bash` (or `zsh`):

```
4s-import <(zcat huge.gz)
```

This operator will create a temporary fifo `/dev/fd/NN` and replace `<(.)` with the string `/dev/fd/NN`. `4s-import` now can open `/dev/fd/NN` and read from that fifo, while `bash` will run `zcat huge.gz`, which sends its output to `/dev/fd/NN`.

Answer (score 17):

1. Many programs have a `-` as standard input. If yours does, use that as it's "builtin".
2. You can also try using `/dev/stdin` or `/dev/fd/0` as a file.
3. A third option is to use `mkfifo` to create a fifo special file. In one shell you pipe in your data (eg. `gunzip > your_fifo_file`), while in the other you call your program with the fifo as the file.